# Am I being robbed of my rightful review queue badges?

Tags: support, badges, review

I've never really taken much notice of "review queue progress" (or badges in general, to be honest). But I just realised that although [several other users have a **steward** gold badge](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/126/steward) (for completing at least 1,000 review tasks), I'm barely halfway there. But I think I do my fair share of reviewing.

I think the reason for this is that when I'm looking at entries that are only in the review queue because someone closevoted, I often feel I don't have enough information to make a decision without "drilling down" to look at the entire post (by clicking on the *Question Title* as shown within the entry for that item in the review queue).

So nine times out of ten, if I'm going to add my own closevote, I do it from that "lower level", then click my browser "back" button to return to the review queue. At that point, the display shows ***This item is not reviewable***, so I click on "next" to look at the next item in the queue.

I've just established that my current progress level was 537 (which I assume is *total closevote items reviewed since I signed up to ELU*, at which time there was one item in the *closevote* queue. I went through out my normal procedure as above, and my badge progress still says 537.

I don't know if I'm misunderstanding the situation here, and I've no idea if it's even practical for the system to realise what I'm doing and credit me with having performed the review there, but I have the distinct feeling ***I wuz robbed***! So I'm tagging this "bug" as well as "feature-request".

---

EDIT:
If I *am* being robbed, can I be the second user ever on ELU to sport an [***unsung hero***](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/badges/35/unsung-hero) badge?

Answer (score 1):

Just open the question in a new tab. The vote page will be there waiting for you on the original tab when you're finished looking at the question.

Comment: Easy enough to do, but in over three years of reviewing I've never noticed anyone saying *"If you don't adopt this workaround, you won't be credited for doing all this donkey-work".*

Comment: Being an ass, I am offended by that remark.

Comment: @FumbleFingers you can have my review badges.  It is an issue with the system that they only measure those reviews from within the review context (when edits to posts can work both ways).  It is a small bug or at the very least not explained.  But you also did all that work and didn't ever notice your counter wasn't going up?  I hope you aren't answering on Math SE haha.

Comment: @RyeɃreḁd: It's just that I've noticed a couple of issues about badges lately (they may [affect my closevote powers](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4816/), and I saw merit in ["curiosity" badges](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/4897/)). So I got interested in what the **steward** badge meant, and wondered why ***I*** haven't got one despite being quite an active closevoter and queue-clearer. If it hadn't been for those two issues coming so close together I'd probably not have thought about this one for another three years.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - That makes sense.  I was surprised to see my gold badge.  I really didn't want it since it makes me seem less militant.  I will just tell people I hacked SE to get it or beat up a mod.

Answer (score 0):

I would hope when someone takes an action to close a question or reopen a question outside of the review pages that it counts.  Both of these actions should be encouraged and most users don't use the review pages.  If this isn't working I think it is a bug.

Comment: I closevote a lot of questions simply because I come across them in the list of ***newest*** or ***active*** lists. I can see that if the purpose of the ***steward*** badge is to recognise time spent clearing the review queue, those closevotes shouldn't count (in fact, if I'm the *first* to closevote, I'm actually *adding* to the queue, not *clearing* it). But in the scenario I describe in the question (which is common for me) I really did close *because* I found it in the queue, and I really am *clearing* the queue.

Comment: I don't see the difference.  Either way you are still doing a mod task.  Adding to the queue is actually more important on most SE sites - I know it doesn't seem it here.

Comment: I see a certain amount of difference between offering my (unsolicited) opinion (through a closevote) on questions I just happen to be looking at, and consciously going through my review queue to (which the system would obviously *like* me to do), in order to either endorse or disagree with the opinions of others who've already recommended some action or other.

Comment: There is a slight difference but both are equally important.  Obviously they want people to see/use the review page but at the same time doing the initial vote is just as important.  For your specific case it seems like an easy rule to write... if {(closevote != 0) then (give FF badge points)}.  Your example is really the extreme of the interface being confusing or not working.  Really there are 1000s of SE rules and they do a great job.  This is one that I have implemented on our internal SE clone.

Comment: @ RyeɃreḁd: Having thought about it in light of your comment there, it seems to me it *should* be reasonably easy for the back-room boys to code up something that notices *why* they're displaying *"This item is not reviewable"* - if it's simply because I have just closevoted it, obviously I deserve credit. I'd accept that as reasonable, even if *sometimes* I don't actually get the credit because I never use the browser "back" button to return to the queue reviewing task. Perhaps this should be an SE.meta complaint.

Comment: @FumbleFingers - I think it is SE meta.  Along the same lines I would implemented a styling difference on close votes != 0 and reopen != 0.  It is common sense that you need to alert people that there is a close/reopen debate with a question.  Some of the SE rules count on everyone understanding a complex set of rules that only heavy users will or programmers.